# How to use Intel MKL Libraries in Dymola 2021

Tags: dymola

I am aware of support for Intel Compiler in Dymola 2021 but I don't know if Intel MKL variants are used for the linear algebra libraries (BLAS, LAPACK etc.) in the solver. I was wondering if there is some setting to switch the solvers to use the MKL variants.

I tried using the `-Qmkl` compiler flag but I am unsure if that makes any difference

Update: Looks like Dymola isn't making use of MKL libraries even if you select the intel compiler. MKL_VERBOSE seems to have confirmed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel MKL (BLAS, LAPACK, FFT ) provides the Verbose mode feature - all of these routines print a human-readable line describing the call. To enable this mode you may set/export the MKL_VERBOSE=1 environment variable. Please refer more details to the developer guide follow the link:https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mkl-linux-developer-guide/top/managing-output/using-intel-mkl-verbose-mode.html